# Flexdashboard slowness

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I created a Flexdashboard on COVID19 along with a simulation using the SIR model. I want to share the same, however, the application takes a long time to compile either on the computer or on the phone. I would like some idea to make the application lighter with the same structure! Maybe store somewhere else, or create the same application on shiny, without using Flexdashboard? Does anyone have any suggestions? The source code can be seen in the application at this link: [Click Here!](https://fsbmat.shinyapps.io/CoronaBR/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I used the fread function of the data.table package to read the .csv database.